# Iteratively generate results for all different combinatiosn for a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, apply

My data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:5, each = 80*3), year = rep(rep(2000:2002, each = 80), times = 5), 
             daily.rain = runif(min = 0, max = 30, 80*5*3))
df.clim <- df %>% group_by(loc.id,year) %>% summarise(tot.rain = sum(daily.rain)) %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(loc.id) %>%
      summarise(mean.rain = mean(tot.rain))
df <- df %>% left_join(df.clim)
```

This data has 5 locations. For each location, I have 80 days of rainfall data for 3 years as well as a column which specifies the mean total rainfall for that location

I have a vector of percentage

```
per.vec <- seq(from = 1, to = 59, by = 2)
```

What I want to do is: For each location and year, I want to calculate no. of days it takes to reach:

```
  from 1% to 3% of mean.rain
  from 1% to 5% of mean.rain,
  .
  .
  from 1% to 59% of mean.rain,
  from 2% to 3% of mean.rain
  from 2% to 5% of mean.rain
   .
   .
  from 2% to 59% of mean.rain
   .
   .
  from 57% to 59% of mean.rain
```

My final data should look like:

```
  loc.id    year   1-3  1-5 . . . 1-59 2-3 2-5. . .57-59 
    1       2000
    1       2001
    1       2002
    2       2000
    2       2001
    2       2002
    .        .
    5       2001
    5       2002
    5       2003
```

This is something I have never done in R so wondered what would be possible approach to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this turns out to be a data frame with 871 columns so it takes a while to do with a nested for loop.  I'm sure there is a better way to generate columns on the fly.

```
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:5, each = 80*3), year = rep(rep(2000:2002, each = 80), times = 5), 
             daily.rain = runif(min = 0, max = 30, 80*5*3))
df.clim <- df %>% group_by(loc.id,year) %>% summarise(tot.rain = sum(daily.rain)) %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(loc.id) %>%
  summarise(mean.rain = mean(tot.rain))
df <- df %>% left_join(df.clim)
```

First you can generate the running sum of the rain for each year by using `group_by` and adding a row with `mutate` that does a `cumsum` for each year at each location id.

```
#get daily rain total
df <- df %>% group_by(loc.id,year) %>% mutate(totalrain = cumsum(daily.rain))
```

Next we can choose the two vectors that you want to iterate over.  In this case your inside vector is from 3 to 59 by 2 and your outside is from 1 to 57.

```
per.vec <- seq(from = 3, to = 59, by = 2)
per.vec2 <- 1:57
```

We then loop through the set of numbers and generate a new column each time with the `mutate` function that does a comparison to see if the rainfall total at that day is between the two percentages.

```
#get comparison for each level
for (x in per.vec2) {
  for (y in per.vec) {
    if(x<y) {
      df <- df %>% group_by(loc.id,year) %>% mutate(!!paste(x," - ",y,"% of mean",collapse = "") := (totalrain >= mean.rain*(x/100)) & (totalrain <= mean.rain*(y/100)))

}}}
```

Last we use `dplyr`'s summarise function in combination with `group_by` to do sums at each of the columns to count the number of days that the total rainfall was in between the percentages.

```
#get the total number of days by summing
results <- df[,-(3:5)] %>% group_by(loc.id,year) %>%summarise_all(funs(sum))
head(results[,1:7])
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups: loc.id [2]
#   loc.id  year `1  -  3 % of mean` `1  -  5 % of mean` `1  -  7 % of mean` `1  -  9 % of mean` `1  -  11 % of mean`
#    <int> <int>               <int>               <int>               <int>               <int>                <int>
# 1      1  2000                   3                   4                   6                   8                    8
# 2      1  2001                   1                   2                   3                   5                    7
# 3      1  2002                   1                   2                   3                   6                    7
# 4      2  2000                   2                   3                   3                   4                    5
# 5      2  2001                   3                   4                   5                   7                    9
# 6      2  2002                   1                   3                   4                   6                    7
```